# Probability of highest score in Yahtzee?

Tags: probability

Can somebody check my work, but the probability of actually getting the right Yahtzee for every turn is one Yahtzee for each number 1 through 5 times 4 Yahtzees of 6 times 4 Yahtzees of anything else. $\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{1}{6}\bigr)^5\cdot3\Bigr)^5\biggr)\cdot\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{1}{6}\bigr)^5\cdot3\Bigr)^4\biggr)\cdot\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{1}{6}\bigr)^4\cdot3\Bigr)^4\biggr)$

The reason it is only 4 powers of 1/6 is because it can be anything eliminating the first die as a factor.

It won’t let me use mathjax

Comment: Enclose mathematical equations with dollar signs to initiate math mode.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information on using MathJax here.

Comment: It is not clear what rules you are using for your very specific yahtzee game.  There are various rule variants which can change the maximum score, for example if you roll five of a kind after your first yahtzee you may replace anything else on the board with a five of a kind for some number of points (*higher than it would have otherwise been*), in other variants you may only replace things from the lower part of the score sheet but not the upper.  In other variants, no replacement is allowed, and so you are still expected to get straights and full houses, etc...

Comment: Looking more closely at what work you *have* shown, it does not appear correct for many reasons.  Firstly, you have the term $(\frac{1}{6})^5\cdot 3$ which appears to be your calculation for getting a yahtzee of a specific number in a specific round of play.  You have multiplied by three, presumably because you are taking into account the three different times you are allowed to roll.  Multiplying by three does *not* have the effect you hope.  If you flip a coin three times in a row trying to get a heads, you do not have a probability of $0.5\cdot 3=1.5$ of having gotten a heads.

Comment: You have neglected to take into account any sort of strategic keeping of dice.  For example, if on my first roll I rolled four 6's and a two, I could choose to keep the sixes and reroll the two, thus increasing my odds.  Finally, you have not taken into account that you can choose to accomplish the tasks on the yahtzee scorecard in any order you choose and do not need to do the tasks in the order listed, which again further increases your chances.  Taking all of the strategy into account, the full probability calculations will be long and tedious and beyond the scope of this site.